# list RDS snapshot created today using Boto 3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am doing a Python Lambda function to describe list of RDS snapshots created today. The challenge is how to convert the datetime.datetime.today() into a format which RDS client understands?

UPDATE: I have implemented some changes suggested, I have added a string variable to convert the date expression into format which Boto3 RDS understands.

> 'SnapshotCreateTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),

```
today = (datetime.today()).date()
rds_client = boto3.client('rds')
snapshots = rds_client.describe_db_snapshots(SnapshotType='automated')

harini = "datetime("+ today.strftime('%Y,%m,%d') + ")"
print harini

print snapshots

for i in snapshots['DBSnapshots']:
    if i['SnapshotCreateTime'].date() == harini:
        print(i['DBSnapshotIdentifier'])
        print (today)
```

it is still unable to retrieve list of automated snapshots created today

Answer (score 4):

SnapshotCreateTime is a datetime.datetime object. So, you can just do `i['SnapshotCreateTime'].date()` to get the date.

```
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timezone

today = (datetime.today()).date()
rds_client = boto3.client('rds')
snapshots = rds_client.describe_db_snapshots()

for i in snapshots['DBSnapshots']:
    if i['SnapshotCreateTime'].date() == today:
        print(i['DBSnapshotIdentifier'])
        print (today)
```

Comment: hi, I updated the question, the datetime format doesn't match the one required by the RDS describe db snapshots

Comment: you don't need `harini` just compare with `today`, that should work.